# When I start project I get Internal Server Error in WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, rest, web-config

When I start asp.net mvc project I get error.Internal Server Error.
I host asp.net mvc and wcf application on IIS express.

```
 <services>
      <service name="WCFSkyAuction.Service.UserRoleService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WCFSkyAuction.Service.UserRoleServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" name="UserService" contract="WCFSkyAuction.Service.UserRoleService" />
      </service>
      <service name="WCFSkyAuction.Service.AdminRoleService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WCFSkyAuction.Service.AdminRoleServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" name="AdminService" contract="WCFSkyAuction.Service.AdminRoleService" />
      </service>
      <service name="WCFSkyAuction.Service.VipRoleService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WCFSkyAuction.Service.VipRoleServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFSkyAuction.Service.VipRoleService"/>
      </service>
      <service name="WCFSkyAuction.Service.MailService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WCFSkyAuction.Service.MailServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFSkyAuction.Service.MailService" />
      </service>
    </services>



 <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFSkyAuction.Service.UserRoleServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WCFSkyAuction.Service.AdminRoleServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WCFSkyAuction.Service.VipRoleServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WCFSkyAuction.Service.MailServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
```

That's my config file on WCF side I have each endpoint with webHttp binding and contract on 4 svc files.All methods has correct set in svc files with operationcontract, with one argument.I have cheacked services is cool.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/WCFSkyAuction/Service/UserRoleService.svc"
        binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" behaviorConfiguration="webhttp" contract="UserService.UserRoleService"
        name="UserService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/WCFSkyAuction/Service/AdminRoleService.svc" 
                binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webhttp" contract="AdminService.AdminRoleService"
        name="AdminService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webhttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

That's a web.config in asp.net mvc side. I have written client endpoints and behaviors by Edit WCF file.Add Service Referance works good and I added all reference.when I started project with a first operation of service I got Internal Server Error.Communication Exception was uhandled by user code.
Thank you.How can I decide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `<webHttp />` tag to behaviors in server config

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that your c# code threw an exception. Try putting your code in a try catch and log the exception.

Comment: Thanks for posting) When I have traced I saw that I can't to direct to method in service